# Pytest throws import errors in the source code

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, anaconda, pytest

I have a source file that I want to test but I am getting import errors when I run the test. I am using an anaconda environment for the project. I have added the `__init__.py` in both the source directory as well as test directory.

My source file looks like this:

```
from pda.utils.generics import get_project_path

project_dir = get_project_path()


def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

If I comment out the line `project_dir = get_project_path()` then the test runs fine without any errors else I get the below errors with the line uncommented.

```
tests/test_test.py:4: in <module>
    from src.functions.calc2 import *
src/functions/calc2.py:3: in <module>
    project_dir = get_project_path()
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pda/utils/generics.py:253: in get_project_path
    config = get_config(path=None, dir_to_find="conf", sub_dir_to_find="base")
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pda/utils/generics.py:285: in get_config
    tmp_path = os.path.join(tmp_path, name)
/conda_envs/test_env/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py:80: in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
E   TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
===================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================
ERROR tests/test_test.py - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

My test file looks like this:

```
from src.functions.calc2 import *

# test 1
def test_add():
    assert add(1, 2) == 3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the function `get_project_path()` requires input arguments and you are not adding any. Maybe you can navigate to the function definition of `get_project_path` to find out. Moist IDE such ach PyCharm or VSCode support this.

Comment: I have checked the function definition and it does not require any inputs.

Comment: Alright, reading the traceback I think that the function `get_project_path()` calls some function like `get_config(path=None, dir_to_find="conf", sub_dir_to_find="base")`. It is in the traceback you posted. Somehow in your basecode a path has been defined and the function knows where to look. Maybe in the environment vars. Your test class is separated from your basecode and probably cannot find this. I can't see all code of course but if you are using `pytest` for instance you can setup a `pytest.INI` file and define some variables. https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#pytest-ini